# Appendix TOC link does not work when using Polyglossia (TeX Live 2015)

Tags: xetex, hyperref, texlive, polyglossia

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \include{chapter1}
  \begin{appendices}
    \include{appendixA}
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

With this example, the TOC correctly points to the page number of the appendix, but the link does not work (it doesn't point anywhere). Using the PDF's table of contents does not work either. Using `\appendix` works, however.

What's weirder, this only happens with TeX Live 2015, as shipped in Ubuntu 16.04. It does not happen with the previous LTS version.

Is this a known bug? How can I solve it proper?

Comment: `Apéndice.a` is the hyperanchor, which causes troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `polyglossia` allows unicode characters, the name `Apéndice` as content of `\appendixname` causes a problem for the hyperanchor that is to be set for the correct linking.

The `appendix` package defines `\Hy@chapname` to be `\appendixname`, which is `Apéndice` in this case → 'wrong'.

Redefining `\Hy@chapname` cures the problem -- just use a anchorname with 'regular' letters, i.e. no accents. etc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}


\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usebetterlinkanchor}[1]{%
  \def\Hy@chapapp{#1}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \begin{appendices} 
      \usebetterlinkanchor{appendixchapters}
      \chapter{Appendix}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Any ideas on why accented hyperanchors break down on just *this* particular version of XeLaTeX?

Comment: @amyspark: I don't know -- did it work in a previous version?

Comment: It did in TeX Live 2013.

Comment: @amyspark: I can't check with TL 2013, unfortunately, but there have been some updates to `polyglossia`, but I think the issue is rather how `xelatex` builds up the links.