# Cross reference between mathematical expressions

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I have a LaTeX file that I want to make a reference in the appendix to have the demonstration of an equation, but when I put the code it only shows me the section, it does not move to there. I have the following:

I have added the working code, when I try to add the package hyperref it does not load. Sorry because the content is in Spanish

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afour25}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\compconj}[1]
{
  \overline{#1}
}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\lhead{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
%\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\title{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
\author{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{ Preliminares}

\subsection{ Algo sobre álgebra lineal}


\subsubsection{Definición matriz transpuesta conjugada}

La transpuesta conjugada de una matriz $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ se define como:
\[A^*:=\compconj{(A^{\top})}=(\compconj{A})^{\top} \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

Esta matriz transpuesta conjugada tiene las siguientes propiedades:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $(A+B)^*=A^* +B^*$ teniendo  $\forall A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_1}
    \item $(A B)^*=B^* A^*$ teniendo $\forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ y  $\forall B\in \mathbb{C}^{n*p}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_2}
    \item $(\lambda A)^*=\compconj{\lambda} A^*$ teniendo $ \forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ y $\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, demostración en:  \ref{eqn:demostracion_3}
    \item $(A^*)^*=A$ teniendo $\forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_4}
    \item $(A^{-1})^*=(A^*)^{-1}$ teniendo $ \forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_5}
\end{enumerate}


\subsection{Observaciones}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Todas las propiedades de las matrices reales con las operaciones del álgebra lineal para el caso real siguen siendo ciertas en el caso complejo, con demostraciones idénticas porque solo usan la estructura de cuerpo $\mathbb{R}$ y $\mathbb{C}$ también lo es.
\end{itemize}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Demostraciones:}
\subsection{Demostración 1}\label{eqn:demostracion_1}

\[(A+B)^{*}=A^{*}+B^{*}\]

\[[(A+B)^{*}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{(A+B)})^{\top}]_{j,k}=\compconj{[(A+B)^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{[A+B]_{k,j}}=\compconj{[A]_{k,j}}+\compconj{[B]_{k,j}}=\]

\[=\compconj{[A^{\top}]_{j,k}}+\compconj{[B^{\top}]_{j,k}}=[A^{*}]_{j,k}+[B^{*}]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 2}\label{eqn:demostracion_2}

\[(A*B)^{*}=B^{*}*A^{*}\]

\[[(A*B)^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A*B)^{\top}}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A*B)]_{j,k}^{\top}}=[\compconj{(A*B)]_{k,j}}=[\compconj{A}]_{k,p}*[\compconj{B}]_{p,j}=\]

\[=[\compconj{B^{\top}}]_{j,p}*[\compconj{A^{\top}}]_{p,k}=[B^{*}]_{j,p}*[A^{*}]_{p,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*p}\]
\[\forall B \in \mathbb{C}^{p*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 3}\label{eqn:demostracion_3}

\[(\lambda*A)*=\compconj{\lambda}*A^{*}\]

\[[(\lambda * A)^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{((\lambda *  A)^{\top})}]_{j,k}=\compconj{[(\lambda *  A)^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{[\lambda *  A]_{k,j}}=\compconj{\lambda * [A]_{k,j}}=\compconj{\lambda} *  \compconj{[A]_{k,j}}=\]

\[=\compconj{\lambda} *  \compconj{[A^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{\lambda} *  [\compconj{(A^{\top})}]_{j,k}=\compconj{\lambda} *  [A^*]_{j,k}=[\compconj{\lambda} * A^*]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 4}\label{eqn:demostracion_4}

\[(A^{*})^{*}=A\]

\[[(A^{*})^{*}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{((\compconj{A})^{\top}})^{\top}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(\compconj{A})^{\top}}]_{k,j}=[(\compconj{\compconj{A}})^{\top}]_{k,j}=[\compconj{\compconj{A}}]_{j,k}=[A]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 5}\label{eqn:demostracion_5}

\[[A^{-1}]^{*}=[A^{*}]^{-1}\]

\[[(A^{-1})^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A^{-1})^{\top}}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{A^{-1}})^{\top}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{A^{-1}})]_{k,j}=[(\compconj{A})^{-1}]_{k,j}=[((\compconj{A})^{-1})^{\top}]_{j,k}=\]

\[=[((\compconj{A})^{\top})^{-1}]_{j,k}=[(A^{*})^{-1}]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to use a package like hyperref for that.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. In this case, as @remco mentioned, is you probably aren't loading `hyperref`

Comment: Off - Topic: The usage of numbers in labels is discouraged -- as soon as the order of the labeled entities changes the numbers do not match and it is easily forgotten to change the `\ref{....}` occurences as well. Don't do this!

Comment: see if `\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}` in preamble helps. i cant test since you not provide complete but small document. so we haven't any clue, what is your document class ...

Comment: @Zarko: `\setsecnumdepth` is a `memoir` macro, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yes, it is. this is pure guessing, document class of the op document is unknown ...

Comment: @Zarko: The idea however is good, but if I remember correctly, `hyperref` supports linking anchors even if the section etc. isn't numbered. The O.P. seems to use the `appendix` package.

Comment: I have added the code, when I try to add the package hyperref it does not load. Sorry because the content is in Spanish

Comment: @MiguelSanzNarrillos: The problems with `hyperref` are caused by the `appendix` package here. I 'solved' your problem, but I don't address typographical issues with wrong usages of `\[...\]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause is not using `hyperref`, however this will lead to problems with `\Hy@chapname` being defined to expand as `Apéndice`, the accented character means trouble.

Using another name as done here with `\usebetterlinkanchor` cures the problem. (See [Appendix TOC link does not work when using Polyglossia (TeX Live 2015)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306133/appendix-toc-link-does-not-work-when-using-polyglossia-tex-live-2015))

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{afour25}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usebetterlinkanchor}[1]{%
  \gdef\Hy@chapapp{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\compconj}[1]{%
  \overline{#1}
}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\lhead{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
%\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\title{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
\author{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{ Preliminares}

\subsection{ Algo sobre álgebra lineal}


\subsubsection{Definición matriz transpuesta conjugada}

La transpuesta conjugada de una matriz $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ se define como:
\[A^*:=\compconj{(A^{\top})}=(\compconj{A})^{\top} \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

Esta matriz transpuesta conjugada tiene las siguientes propiedades:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $(A+B)^*=A^* +B^*$ teniendo  $\forall A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_1}
    \item $(A B)^*=B^* A^*$ teniendo $\forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ y  $\forall B\in \mathbb{C}^{n*p}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_2}
    \item $(\lambda A)^*=\compconj{\lambda} A^*$ teniendo $ \forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$ y $\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, demostración en:  \ref{eqn:demostracion_3}
    \item $(A^*)^*=A$ teniendo $\forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_4}
    \item $(A^{-1})^*=(A^*)^{-1}$ teniendo $ \forall A\in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}$, demostración en: \ref{eqn:demostracion_5}
\end{enumerate}


\subsection{Observaciones}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Todas las propiedades de las matrices reales con las operaciones del álgebra lineal para el caso real siguen siendo ciertas en el caso complejo, con demostraciones idénticas porque solo usan la estructura de cuerpo $\mathbb{R}$ y $\mathbb{C}$ también lo es.
\end{itemize}



\begin{appendices}
\usebetterlinkanchor{appendixchapters}
\section{Demostraciones:}
\subsection{Demostración 1}\label{eqn:demostracion_1}

\[(A+B)^{*}=A^{*}+B^{*}\]

\[[(A+B)^{*}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{(A+B)})^{\top}]_{j,k}=\compconj{[(A+B)^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{[A+B]_{k,j}}=\compconj{[A]_{k,j}}+\compconj{[B]_{k,j}}=\]

\[=\compconj{[A^{\top}]_{j,k}}+\compconj{[B^{\top}]_{j,k}}=[A^{*}]_{j,k}+[B^{*}]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 2}\label{eqn:demostracion_2}

\[(A*B)^{*}=B^{*}*A^{*}\]

\[[(A*B)^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A*B)^{\top}}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A*B)]_{j,k}^{\top}}=[\compconj{(A*B)]_{k,j}}=[\compconj{A}]_{k,p}*[\compconj{B}]_{p,j}=\]

\[=[\compconj{B^{\top}}]_{j,p}*[\compconj{A^{\top}}]_{p,k}=[B^{*}]_{j,p}*[A^{*}]_{p,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*p}\]
\[\forall B \in \mathbb{C}^{p*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 3}\label{eqn:demostracion_3}



\[(\lambda*A)*=\compconj{\lambda}*A^{*}\]

\[[(\lambda * A)^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{((\lambda *  A)^{\top})}]_{j,k}=\compconj{[(\lambda *  A)^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{[\lambda *  A]_{k,j}}=\compconj{\lambda * [A]_{k,j}}=\compconj{\lambda} *  \compconj{[A]_{k,j}}=\]

\[=\compconj{\lambda} *  \compconj{[A^{\top}]_{j,k}}=\compconj{\lambda} *  [\compconj{(A^{\top})}]_{j,k}=\compconj{\lambda} *  [A^*]_{j,k}=[\compconj{\lambda} * A^*]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 4}\label{eqn:demostracion_4}

\[(A^{*})^{*}=A\]

\[[(A^{*})^{*}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{((\compconj{A})^{\top}})^{\top}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(\compconj{A})^{\top}}]_{k,j}=[(\compconj{\compconj{A}})^{\top}]_{k,j}=[\compconj{\compconj{A}}]_{j,k}=[A]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\subsection{Demostración 5}\label{eqn:demostracion_5}

\[[A^{-1}]^{*}=[A^{*}]^{-1}\]

\[[(A^{-1})^{*}]_{j,k}=[\compconj{(A^{-1})^{\top}}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{A^{-1}})^{\top}]_{j,k}=[(\compconj{A^{-1}})]_{k,j}=[(\compconj{A})^{-1}]_{k,j}=[((\compconj{A})^{-1})^{\top}]_{j,k}=\]

\[=[((\compconj{A})^{\top})^{-1}]_{j,k}=[(A^{*})^{-1}]_{j,k}\]

\[\forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m*n}\]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the problem is that when the package hyperref is loaded, the pdf does not be output.

Comment: @MiguelSanzNarrillos: Please don't write in Spanish here

Comment: I have edit it, sorry

Comment: @MiguelSanzNarrillos: There's not much I can do for you. It works for me, apart from the `afour4` package I don't have

Comment: It must be an error I do not see, I put that code and works, but not adding only the changes you mention, so thanks